# How to pass two parameters to a \newenvironment?

Tags: macros, floats, parameters

I have defined this new environment for handling my images in my document
I want to pass two parameters: #1 to refer to pathname to the imagefile #2 to refer to the string I want to pass to the label

```
 \newenvironment{insertmyimages}[2][,]%
 {
 \begin{figure}[!h]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{#1}%
 \caption{Fig. #2}
 \end{figure}
 }

 \insertmyimages{./Image.gif, 17}
```

I would like the above to center the image and label this Fig. 17.  How do I do this ?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: `\centering` won't do anything if you use `width=\textwidth`; the image has nowhere to go.

Comment: looks to me as if you need a command.  what you've written could be more concisely expressed as a command, though i don't quite understand it (it seems to make the file name optional, with default ",").  also, your caption will come out as "Figure <number>: Fig. <second arg>" which is surely not right.

Comment: I want the caption to be Figure <number> or Fig <number>. Either one would work. Your observation is correct. I was under the impression that "," is how you separate the #1 and #2, when you use the macro within your document. That was a mistake as well.

Answer (score 4):

This seems like a bit of a strange request- are you sure you don't want to have `LaTeX` generate the figure numbers for you?

If you really do want to do this, then here's one way- note that

- I have changed `\newenvironment` to `\newcommand`
- I have removed `[,]` which means something different from what you intended
- I have used `\setcounter` to change the figure number to what you want

Here's a complete MWE

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\newcommand{\insertmyimages}[2]{%
    \setcounter{figure}{\numexpr#2-1\relax}
    \figure[!htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{#1}%
    \caption{}
    \endfigure
}

\begin{document}
\insertmyimages{./Image.gif}{17}
\end{document}
```

Perhaps you might have wanted

```
\newcommand{\insertmyimages}[2]{%
    \figure[!htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{#1}%
    \caption{}
     \label{#2}
    \endfigure
}
```

to be used as, for example

```
\insertmyimages{./Image.gif}{mylabel}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your valuable input and suggestion. You mentioned that LaTeX can create the figure number automatically. Can you LMK how this can be accomplished ? Many thanks for your prompt response. I think I can make progress in the meantime.

Comment: Ok. I re-used the code. Looks like I am almost there. I seem to get "Figure 1:" under the first figure and so on. Is there a way to get rid of the trailing ":" ? If I got "Figure 1", i think I would be done. Also, I have used \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}; using \usepackage[demo]{graphicx} produces a black rectangle of the size of the image. My document class is memoir.

Comment: @user33731 Add `\captiondelim{}` to the preamble (if you want to suppress the colon and space from the labels for all floats) or to the definition of the new command inside `figure` and before `\caption` (for just figures).